# r: Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript

Tags: r, subscript

I have a column in the dataframe with the values: "Q1", Q2", "Q3", etc. I'm trying to separate the letter "Q" from the numeric values using:

```
DF %>% separate(DF$tmp, c(NA, "Number"), "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])" ).
```

I get the following error:

> "Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript. x Subscript
> var has size 452 but must be size 1. "

I don't get this error if I create the dataframe manually using:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "Q1", "Q2", "Q10"))

df %>% separate(x, c(NA, "B"), "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])" )
```

But I do get the error when working with the existing dataframe (I checked, and `is.dataframe` returns `TRUE`)

Comment: The `DF$tmp` is wrong in `separate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should be

```
DF %>% 
    separate(tmp, c("Other", "Number"), "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tidyr::extract` -

```
tidyr::extract(df, x, c("A", "B"), '(Q)(\\d+)')

#     A    B
#1 <NA> <NA>
#2    Q    1
#3    Q    2
#4    Q   10
```

If you are interested only in the numeric part there are lot of other options.

```
#1.
tidyr::extract(df, x, "B", 'Q(\\d+)')
#2.
sub('Q(\\d+)', '\\1', df$x)
#3.
sub('Q', '', df$x)
#4.
stringr::str_extract(df$x, '\\d+')
#5.
readr::parse_number(df$x)
```